# apply discounts from database mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in mysql which stores Discounts applicable on restaurants. Structure is as below:

```
id    res_id    disc_amt    disc_percntge
------------------------------------------
 1       2         300          15
 2       2         500          25

$sqldisc = "select * from disc_n_coupons where restaurant_id=?";
$datadisc = DB::instance()->prepare($sqldisc)->execute
            (array($_SESSION['res_in_sess']))->fetchAll();
```

Now, i want to apply that if cart total has reached to `disc_amt` then `disc_percntge` shall be applied.
Currently both the discounts are getting applied i.e. If Total in cart has reached `500` then `15%` is applied and then on discounted price again `25%` is getting applied.But i want only one disc to be applied as per amount mentioned.

Below is my logic

```
foreach($datadisc as $rowsdisc){
    if($subtl>$rowsdisc['disc_amt']){
        echo $subtl."*".$rowsdisc['disc_percntge']."/"."100";
        $subtldisc = ($subtl*$rowsdisc['disc_percntge'])/100;
    }
$subtl = $subtl-$subtldisc;
}
```

Comment: How you selecting the coupons to apply? in where it is only `restaurant_id `

Comment: What is `fm_disc_on`? Can't see it in the table...

Comment: yes @senk .. discounts will be applied as per restaurant id only

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson ... i corrected that column now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see to that the query returns discounts in descending order, biggest amount first (if a bigger discount applies, the smaller ones following should be ignored)

```
$sqldisc = "select * from disc_n_coupons where restaurant_id=? ORDER BY disc_amt DESC";
```

Then all you need to do is break the loop once the first allowed discount has been applied, something like;

```
foreach($datadisc as $rowsdisc) {

    if($subtl < $rowsdisc['disc_amt'])
        continue;

    echo $subtl."*".$rowsdisc['disc_percntge']."/"."100";
    $subtldisc = ($subtl*$rowsdisc['disc_percntge'])/100;
    $subtl = $subtl-$subtldisc;
    break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use limit the query to apply one offer

```
$sqldisc = "select * from disc_n_coupons where restaurant_id=? and disc_amt >=? order by disc_amt desc limit 1";
$datadisc = DB::instance()->prepare($sqldisc)->execute
            (array($_SESSION['res_in_sess'],$subtl))->fetchAll();
```

Comment: your logic will not even return anyrow as `disc_amt` can also not be eqaual